# How to handle request on interceptor after getting the value from an observable on rxjs and angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

So I'm coming from an AngularJS background while learning Angular 5, I still can't wrap my head around observables.

I'm trying to write an HTTP interceptor for my authentication service. However when I try to get a value from the `localstorage` service (or any observable at this point) I'm not quite sure how to properly return the `next.handle(req)` method from the observable after getting the data (using subscribe?)

Here's my current code (which does not work):

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthinterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private storage: LocalStorage) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.storage.getItem('authToken').subscribe(res => {
      return next.handle(req);
    });
  }    

}
```

Notice I'm not doing anything with the data, simply trying to return the Observable> object from within my async call

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning an Observable inside `subscribe` won't do anything. You need to merge it into the chain. For example like this:

```
return this.storage.getItem('authToken')
  .mergeMap(res => next.handle(req));
```

Comment: Thannks Martin, this actually worked. I'm still not quite sure what I'm doing with this so I'm going to do some more reading.

I was also able to perform the same functionality with something like this:

   return this.storage.getItem('authToken')
      .switchMap(r => { return next.handle.req(); });